# View events are not working in Marionette

Tags: javascript, google-maps, backbone.js, marionette

I am rendering `div` element with textbox's and buttons on top of `google.maps` using `infobox` concept.Just like in the following way.

[image]

Previous I mention,Even if user any values enters on textboxs their corresponding functions are not triggering.Sorry actually it's working fine,I didn't check properly.For reference I put screenshot.

[image]

But I observed one thing,If the user click on `a` elements,their corresponding functions are not triggering.I put screenshot for reference.

[image]

html code:

```
 <a href="#" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-block btn-inverse" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#infoModal" id="photoBtn">Photo</a>
                <a href="#" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-block btn-danger" id="removeBtn">Remove</a>
```

view code:

[image]

`freshtimeMapId` refers entire `div` element,where `map` renders.Why I mention `freshtimeMapId` as a `el` element, all custom elements are renders in between `freshtimeMapId(div)` element.But events are not triggering .

How can I fix this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: That code seems to work. Are you sure the selector for your div is correct? See - http://jsfiddle.net/K7YZ5/1/

Comment: @net.uk.sweet sorry man,before post the question I didn't check properly actually it's working fine.I updated my question can you check it once.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your updated code either: http://jsfiddle.net/fy5PY/1/

Comment: @net.uk.sweet I don't know, why it's not working my code.Some functions are working which are corresponds to `textboxs`,some functions are not working which are corresponds to `a` tag.While testing time I made screenshots and attached them.can you check it once.let me know what's the wrong.

Comment: That code looks okay to me too. Best thing I can suggest is that you try to put together a basic example in http://jsfiddle.net which demonstrates the issue. I'm pretty sure someone will be able to help if you can do that.

Comment: Where is the template?